# Converting from hex to binary and binary to hex, without using conversion, reading txt file to find errors in RAM

Tags: java, ram

I am attempting to create a java program which converts hexadecimal possible errors from a RAM location in a computer. Then switch from hex to binary, and binary to decimal to find the location of which RAM is corrupted. This is the code I have so far:

```
public class Practice {

private static String result;
private static int j;

public static void hexToBinary() throws IOException {
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("RAMerrors.txt"));

result = "";
String binVal; // the binary value of the Hex

while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = infile.nextLine();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(line);
    String hex = input.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
        char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);

        switch (hexChar) {
            case ('0'):
                binVal = "0000";
                break;
            case ('1'):
                binVal = "0001";
                break;
            case ('2'):
                binVal = "0010";
                break;
            case ('3'):
                binVal = "0011";
                break;
            case ('4'):
                binVal = "0100";
                break;
            case ('5'):
                binVal = "0101";
                break;
            case ('6'):
                binVal = "0110";
                break;
            case ('7'):
                binVal = "0111";
                break;
            case ('8'):
                binVal = "1000";
                break;
            case ('9'):
                binVal = "1001";
                break;
            case ('A'):
                binVal = "1010";
                break;
            case ('B'):
                binVal = "1011";
                break;
            case ('C'):
                binVal = "1100";
                break;
            case ('D'):
                binVal = "1101";
                break;
            case ('E'):
                binVal = "1110";
                break;
            case ('F'):
                binVal = "1111";
                break;
            default:
                binVal = "invalid input";
                break;


        }
         result += binVal;
    }
    System.out.println("Binary of " + hex + ":" + result);

  }

 }

public static void binaryToDecimal() {
    double j=0;
for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++)
{
    if(result.charAt(i)== '1')
    {
     j= j + Math.pow(2, result.length()-1-i);
    }

}
System.out.println("Decimal value: " + j);

}




public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {

    hexToBinary();
    binaryToDecimal();
}

}
```

The hex to binary is fine. The decimal part is only showing me one number (and its not the correct value). Not really sure what loop to use or how to run the binary to decimal part. Thanks in advance for any advice! The txt file has these values:

```
ABCDEFABC
1A00D0000
7A0EDF301
3CDAEFFAD
```

Comment: And you are not allowed to use any built-in Java conversion tools?

Comment: Java has some classes like [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) that might be useful.

Comment: I've tried to run your code with the first input (ABCDEFABC). The decimal value is 46118402748 and your code's output is 4.6118402748E10 which is the same - you are using `double` as the result. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: if you data is stored as binary, i suggest reading it in binary, not text

Comment: I am not allowed to use the conversion tools @callyalater

Comment: @TDG its only giving one value, not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your question was unclear to me. The reason that you get only one number is that you call from `main` to `hexToBinary`, loop thru the entire file with this method, and then return to `main`. After that, you call to `binaryToDecimal` which prints out the value of `result`, which is the last value it got from `hexToBinary`.
What you need to do is to read a value from the file, convert it to binary and then to decimal and proceed to the next value. One way of doing it is this:
Change your methods to return a value and to get a parameter.
`hexToBinary` should be -

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    String binVal; // the binary value of the Hex
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
        char hexChar = hex.charAt(i);

        switch (hexChar) {
            case ('0'):
                binVal = "0000";
                break;
            case ('1'):
                binVal = "0001";
                break;
            case ('2'):
                binVal = "0010";
                break;
            case ('3'):
                binVal = "0011";
                break;
            case ('4'):
                binVal = "0100";
                break;
            case ('5'):
                binVal = "0101";
                break;
            case ('6'):
                binVal = "0110";
                break;
            case ('7'):
                binVal = "0111";
                break;
            case ('8'):
                binVal = "1000";
                break;
            case ('9'):
                binVal = "1001";
                break;
            case ('A'):
                binVal = "1010";
                break;
            case ('B'):
                binVal = "1011";
                break;
            case ('C'):
                binVal = "1100";
                break;
            case ('D'):
                binVal = "1101";
                break;
            case ('E'):
                binVal = "1110";
                break;
            case ('F'):
                binVal = "1111";
                break;
            default:
                binVal = "invalid input";
                break;
        }
         result += binVal;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

`binaryToDecimal` should be -

```
public static Double binaryToDecimal(String result) {
    double j=0;
for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++)
{
    if(result.charAt(i)== '1')
    {
     j= j + Math.pow(2, result.length()-1-i);
    }

}
return j;
}
```

And the `main` will read the file, pass the values to both methods and print the result:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("RAMerrors.txt"));
    String result;
    Double decimal;

    while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = infile.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(line);
        String hex = input.next();
        result = hexToBinary(hex);
        System.out.println("Binary of " + hex + ":" + result);
        decimal = binaryToDecimal(result);
        System.out.println("Decimal value: " + decimal);            
    }
```

The output is

> Binary of ABCDEFABC:101010111100110111101111101010111100 Decimal value: 4.6118402748E10
>     Binary of 1A00D0000:000110100000000011010000000000000000
>     Decimal value: 6.980173824E9
>   Binary of 7A0EDF301:011110100000111011011111001100000001
>   Decimal value: 3.2764719873E10
>   Binary of 3CDAEFFAD:001111001101101011101111111110101101
>   Decimal value: 1.6335699885E10

Hope this is helpful for you.